# Write pseudo code in latex

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to write pseudo code in my paper. Here is the snippet and image like what I want.  Can some one please help me to format it.

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}

\State $stringlen\gets length of string$
\State $i\gets patlen$

top:
 \eIf{i > stringlen}{
   return false\;
   }
   {
   \State $j\gets patlen$
  }

loop:
 \eIf{ j == 0}{
   return j+1\;
   }
   {
         \eIf{string(i) > pat(j)}{
            \State $j\gets $j -1$
            \State $i\gets $i -1$
            \State goto loop
            \State Close.
           }
           {
           \State $j\gets patlen$
          }
  }

\EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

it should look like this:

[image]

Currently it looks messed up. Any help is appreciable ..

Comment: Don't overlook (like I did!) the excellent and brand spanking new (2015) package `algorithm2e`!

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms This wiki page provides a nice overview of several packages to achieve such things.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

This is what can be done with `algorithmicx`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{My algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{MyProcedure}{}
\State $\textit{stringlen} \gets \text{length of }\textit{string}$
\State $i \gets \textit{patlen}$
\BState \emph{top}:
\If {$i > \textit{stringlen}$} \Return false
\EndIf
\State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
\BState \emph{loop}:
\If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
\State $j \gets j-1$.
\State $i \gets i-1$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
\State \textbf{close};
\EndIf
\State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it do `while` as well?

Comment: Yes it does. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms

Comment: It's having problems with seeing \def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm} - how can I fix this? - Undefinied control sequence \BState ->\State \hskip -\ALG ...

Comment: I would rather recommend algorithm2e, since that is currently maintained: https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e

Comment: @lindhe notice first that this answer is more than 3 years old. Also, the fact that the latest version of `algorithm2e` is newer than `algorithmicx` doesn't mean that the latter is obsolete!

Comment: Funny, you start with "what can be done with `algorithmicx`", but then in you code you use packages `algorithm` and `algpseudocode`...

Comment: @JHBonarius `algpseudocode` is part of the `algorithmicx` bundle.

Comment: Ah, but there's also a package called `algorithmicx`.. Why shoudn't I just use that one?

Comment: How to exit the `\BState` and start the next line without the indent? e.g. at what if I have more code, outside of the loop? Must I define another "BState" type but modified?