# Formatting an algorithm with a nice presentation

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx

I was reading [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02113) and I think is really nice the format how they present the algorithms, how can I do this? what packages are needed and the styles.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163768/write-pseudo-code-in-latex, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204592/how-to-format-a-pseudocode-algorithm?lq=1, and many more

Comment: also you can download the source files and check them for pointers