# Highlighting pseudocode in algorithm

Tags: tikz-pgf, algorithm2e, highlighting, algorithmic, pseudocode

**Edit: I "solved" my main issues now. It's a bit ugly/hacky, but at least the result looks ok. With this edit I'm replacing the now obsolete old code with what I have now. But suggestions for improvement are always welcome.**

Goal: Pseudocode with highlighted regions and corresponding annotations on the right hand side. How it looks now:
[image]
Questions:

- <strike>**The horizontal width of the colorboxes**. I would want them to go all the way to the right and include the right hand side comments. (They should all end at the same spot.)</strike> "Solved" by duplicating my own boxit command. Ugly and not portable.
- <strike>**The color is in front of the text**, it would be more readable if it was in the background.</strike> Solved

The code for this is here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}

% colors
\usepackage{xcolor, amsmath}
\definecolor{amaranth}{rgb}{0.9, 0.17, 0.31}
\colorlet{green}{green!20}
\colorlet{yellow}{yellow!60}
\colorlet{red}{red!30}

% pseudocode formatting
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\renewcommand{\KwSty}[1]{\textnormal{\textcolor{amaranth!90!black}{\bfseries #1}}\unskip}
\renewcommand{\ArgSty}[1]{\textnormal{\ttfamily #1}\unskip}
\SetKwComment{Comment}{\color{green!80!black!190}// }{}
\renewcommand{\CommentSty}[1]{\textnormal{\ttfamily\color{green!80!black!190}#1}\unskip}
\newcommand{\var}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\FuncCall}[2]{\texttt{\bfseries #1(#2)}}
\SetKwProg{Function}{function}{}{}
\SetKw{Continue}{continue}
\renewcommand{\ProgSty}[1]{\texttt{\bfseries #1}}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\SetAlgorithmName{Pseudocode}{algorithmautorefname}

% pseudocode highlighting
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}
% two slightly different boxit commands, to ensure the inner boxes end at the same spot
\newcommand{\boxit}[2]{
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node (A) {};\ignorespaces
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[yshift=3pt,fill=#1,opacity=.25,fit={($(A)+(0,0.15\baselineskip)$)($(A)+(.9\linewidth,-{#2}\baselineskip - 0.25\baselineskip)$)}] {};}\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\boxitt}[2]{
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node (A) {};\ignorespaces
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[yshift=3pt,fill=#1,opacity=.25,fit={($(A)+(0,0.15\baselineskip)$)($(A)+(.858\linewidth,-{#2}\baselineskip - 0.25\baselineskip)$)}] {};}\ignorespaces
}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{find\_best\_split}
  \Function{find\_best\_split(X, gradients, curr\_depth)}{

    \tcp{determine node privacy budget}
    \boxit{green}{6.5}
    \eIf (\Comment{params.use\_decay}) {use\_decay} {  
        \boxitt{yellow}{3}
        \eIf (\Comment{curr\_depth == 0}) {curr\_depth == 0} {
            $\var{node\_budget} = \frac{\var{tree\_budget}}{2}$\;
        }{ 
            $\var{node\_budget} = \frac{\var{tree\_budget}}{4}$\;
        }
    }{
        $\var{node\_budget} = \frac{\var{tree\_budget}}{6}$\;
    }
    \tcp{iterate over all possible splits} \boxit{green}{5}
    \For(\Comment{number of cols in X}){feature\_index : features} {
        \boxitt{red}{3.5}
        \For(\Comment{number of rows in X}){feature\_value : X} {
            \If {use\_dp} {
                \Continue
            }
            $\var{gain} = \texttt{\emph{compute\_gain(X, gradients)}}$\;
        }
    }
    $\texttt{TreeNode *node = new TreeNode()}$\;
    \Return{\var{node}}\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest to highlight somehow the sentence "As you can see ... some of those", so it's easier for this community to recognize your question at a glance ;-) Which in fact are more than one ... // Thanks

Comment: Have you reconized the "Related" links on the right, like this one? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204592/how-to-format-a-pseudocode-algorithm?rq=1

Comment: @MS-SPO Thanks, that's a good suggestion, done!
I have not seen the Related section, I'll check it out. :-)