# Box and title of the box containing code

Tags: sourcecode

As the attached picture describe, this is what I am trying to replicate. Now the text does not need to be the same, since I am going to write different content inside but I really like the way this Figure is presented, with a title in between two lines.

[image]

Are they using a package I am missing or a strategy I am not aware of ?

Comment: It can be done with `algorithm` and `algorithmicx` packages. See this answer of mine: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163779/27635

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write an algorithm, see [Write pseudo code in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163768/27635).

Here's an excerpt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{An algorithm}\label{alg:myalgo}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Hello!
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want your figures to have that style, load the `float` package and issue:

```
\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{figure}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}
  \caption{A figure}\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A main strategy is: first define all what you want and second, use it.

For example:

```
% definition

\def\algtitle#1\par{\removelastskip\bigskip\hrule
   \noindent\vrule height12pt depth5pt width0pt #1\par
   \hrule\nobreak\medskip
}
\def\begalg{\removelastskip\medskip
  \bgroup \parindent=0pt \tt \obeylines \obeyspaces  
          \everymath{\catcode`\ =10 \catcode`\^^M=5 }
}
\def\endalg{\egroup\medskip} 
{\obeyspaces\global\def {\ }}

% usage

\algtitle Algorithm 1 Sliding Window

\begalg
for $i$=1 to 4 do
   $S$ = $A_i \cup Q$
   $sw_i$ = $\displaystyle \max_{j=1\ldots|P|} \sum_{w=1\ldots|S|}
            \cases{IC(P_{j+w} & if $P_{j+w}\in S$ \cr
                   0          & otherwise}$
end for
return $sw_{1\ldots4}$
\endalg

\bye
```

The example uses plain TeX. Your question didn't specify the TeX format.

The result:

[image: code]

Comment: what is bye for?

Comment: `\bye` is plain TeX macro which expands to a little work plus `\end` TeX primitive.