# Pseudocode: Algorithm Package boxes all figures

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic

for writing pseudocode I decided to use the solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163768/write-pseudo-code-in-latex). Unfortunately, this package changes the style of all my figures defined like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{AKP13_command_dependency_graph}
    \caption{Command Dependency Graph}
    \label{fig:AKP13_command_dependency_graph}
\end{figure}
```

I would like to have my standard figures without these horizontal lines and with a caption under the figure but my Algorithms like in [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163768/write-pseudo-code-in-latex).

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance :-)

**UPDATE:**
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright, 12pt]{book}
%pseudocode
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
% include graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./arbeit/figures/}}
% fix graphics on defined position
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{AKP13_command_dependency_graph}
    \caption{Command Dependency Graph}
    \label{fig:AKP13_command_dependency_graph}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Dependency Graph Assembly}\label{algo:AKP13_command_dependency_graph_assembly}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{MyProcedure}{}
        \State $\textit{stringlen} \gets \text{length of }\textit{string}$
        \State $i \gets \textit{patlen}$
        \BState \emph{top}:
        \If {$i > \textit{stringlen}$} \Return false
        \EndIf
        \State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
        \BState \emph{loop}:
        \If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
        \State $j \gets j-1$.
        \State $i \gets i-1$.
        \State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
        \State \textbf{close};
        \EndIf
        \State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
        \State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I figured out that my problem comes with these lines:
    \usepackage{float}
    \restylefloat{figure}

I use the because I want my figures to be fixed at the place where I defined them.

Comment: Hmmm... this is not the typical behaviour of the [`algorithm` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms). While it loads [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float), which can be used to restyle the presentation of any float, it only does so for `algorithm`. Can you provide a minimal example that replicates your current behaviour?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to restyle your `figure` float in order to have them be fixed at the place where you define them? That has nothing to do with the restyling of `figure`. Can you explain?

Comment: I took this solution from here: http://tex.lickert.net/tipps/optionh/optionh.html

Answer (score 2):

I've found an incredibly easy workaround.

```
% fix graphics on defined position
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}

%pseudocode
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
```

It works if I change the order of the `\usepackage` calls

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be following [incorrect advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360055/pseudocode-algorithm-package-boxes-all-figures?noredirect=1#comment887296_360055).

The [`algorithm` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) defines the `algorithm` float environment using the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float). So there's no need to load `float` again. Secondly, in order to keep figures "where they're defined", you need to adjust the `\floatplacement` specification, not the style of the float (via `\floatstyle` or `\restylefloat`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{algorithm,graphicx}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\floatplacement{figure}{H}% Figures should always stay where they're defined.

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d.\ of $a$ and $b$}
      \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \While{$r \neq 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is $0$}
        \State $a \gets b$
        \State $b \gets r$
        \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The g.c.d.\ is $b$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note that in my example I don't force `figure` to be placed `[H]`ERE with the `figure` environment. `\floatplacement{figure}{H}` ensures that for *all* figures.

Comment: I now applied [Gernots solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360068/123269). But now I have the problem that algorithms are not placed where they were defined...

Comment: @lukasl1991: You can then use `\floatplacement{algorithm}{H}` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't restyle the `figure` environment, which also affects its layout. An easier way to have a captioned figure staying in place is to load the `capt-of` package (basically a one-line package) and to use the command `\captionof{figure}{...}`:

```
\usepackage{capt-of}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{center}
  ... Code of figure ...
  \captionof{figure}{...The caption of the figure ...}
  \label{...label to refer to figure ...}
\end{center}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright, 12pt]{book}
%pseudocode
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
% include graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./arbeit/figures/}}
% fix graphics on defined position
\usepackage{float}
%\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{Command Dependency Graph}
    \label{fig:AKP13_command_dependency_graph}
\end{center}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Dependency Graph Assembly}\label{algo:AKP13_command_dependency_graph_assembly}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{MyProcedure}{}
        \State $\textit{stringlen} \gets \text{length of }\textit{string}$
        \State $i \gets \textit{patlen}$
        \BState \emph{top}:
        \If {$i > \textit{stringlen}$} \Return false
        \EndIf
        \State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
        \BState \emph{loop}:
        \If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}
        \State $j \gets j-1$.
        \State $i \gets i-1$.
        \State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
        \State \textbf{close};
        \EndIf
        \State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
        \State \textbf{goto} \emph{top}.
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! This approach also works for me. :-)